# Cant get the file upload functionality working with nodejs and express

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multer

I have a form with enctype set to multipart form-data which has one file upload input and there are other text input fields. I do see in the post request that the form is being sent as multi part with the uploaded file. I tried using multer and express-fileupload. Tried all different ways I could try from other stackoverflow threads related to this but I just cant get the file in req.files . Its always undefined. I am not using any middleware. I am just using body-parser which I know does not parse multi-part data. Is there an example on how to get a file upload working with other form fields using the current versions of node and express?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

**Install express and multer**

```
npm install express multer
```

**app.js file:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const multer = require('multer');


// dest -> which tells Multer where to upload the files
const upload = multer({dest:'uploads/'}).single("avatar");


app.post("/profile", (req, res) => {
   upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if(err) {
      res.status(400).send("There is a problem!");
    }
    res.status(200).json({file: req.file});
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => { 
    console.log('Server is runnig on port 3000');
});
```

And run server:

```
node app.js
```

In Postman addressbar set this url: `http://localhost:3000/upload-image`
and you can upload file in Postman and check response.

Also you can upload file in browser without Postman.

```
<form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="avatar" />
</form>
```

**read more details:** [express with multer doc](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html)